# Multiwired small coil

Tags: wire, coil, electromagnetic

I'm looking to make small coils. Or if possible buy a bunch.

But first I started looking into coils. An today I found one that has multiple wires at on side and on the other.

At their end (the connections) they were turned together to make one end on both sides?

so a singlecore multiwired coil.

Question is: Are these better at giving an magnetic field or why do they do this?

This could change my design for my project because they are more studier by the multiple wires that are twisted at the ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about a coil wound with [Litz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire) wire. Litz wire uses multiple individual conductors instead of a single fat conductor in order to reduce the negative consequences of [skin effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) and proximity effect (where high frequency current flows mostly in the outer skin of the conductor, thus increasing the effective resistance and thus power loss). Image from myself:

[image]

It's mostly used for frequencies above audio but below a couple MHz, for example, for induction cooker coils and high frequency switching supply transformers.

Comment: You get proximity effect with two wires and with one winding proximity effect is just skin effect.

Comment: That picture does not show Litz wire. First of all, the strands need to be insulated from each other, and more importantly, they need to be wound such that each strand has "equal time" at the center of the bundle as at the edge.

Comment: @DaveTweed It's not technically "Litz" wire, but everyone seems to call it that- see my edited photo. Of course the conductors have to be insulated from each other or it's just stranded wire- as they are usually magnet wire the insulation may not be obvious.

Comment: That kind of wire will help with proximity effect (which may be the more important effect anyway), but unless it's woven properly, it will not help with regard to skin effect.

Answer (score 0):

At dc, two windings have twice the cross section of one wire hence resistance is lower hence you require less heat loss for a given current in the coil. However, if you are just looking to make a dc electromagnet, it's more space efficient to use a bigger single wire.

However, if you require an AC inductor there will be an operating frequency above which it makes sence to use bifilar windings. As spehro points out this is due to skin effect.

Comment: So those litz wires would require more current? But would their magnetic field be bigger than one with a bigger wire but equal diameter (to make it simple, I do know about the turns and such.). The one I'm talking about has 4 or 5 wires in a litz coils from what I guess is about 28awg (very thin). Would a same diameter from 22awg be better at magnetising? (New question?)

Comment: They're not litz wires if there are only 5 of them. They are parallel bifilar windings and they only "approximate" to litz wire. Either single core or bifilar or litz will produce the same magnetic field for the same current and, as I said in my answer less heat is generated when resistance is lower I.e litz or bifilar don't heat up as much compared to a single strand BUT if you are using dc it won't make one jot of difference if the net cross-sectional-area is the same.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! 

Now I did give the answer to the litz and it's actually bifilar. Hopefully this is will be clear to other questioneers.